# react-i18next inherit language from parent I18nextProvider

Tags: react-i18next

We have a component library where components have their own translations and i18n instances that load them.

I can't figure out how to inherit the `i18n.language` that should exist from a parent context; if using `const { i18n } = useTranslation()` I'm actually getting the i18n instance that will be declared in that component, not the i18n instance from a parent context. Is there a way to get the ancestor i18n instance without directly passing it in as a prop?

Comment: Have you found the solution?

Answer (score 1):

detect for the languageChanged event and change the language also in the other instance.

Like: https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/blob/015c661b00738ea3a05888060956dc9de23108df/example/react-component-lib/src/i18n.js#L28

```
i18n.on('languageChanged', (lng) => {
  i18nOtherLib.changeLanguage(lng);
});
```

Comment: is there any way to get i18n from the parent rather than what will be created via useTranslation / the newly rendered I18nextProvider?